# How to compare 4 different values?

Tags: vb.net, compare

I am wondering how can I compare 4 different values (doubles) from different text files(4) each contains a double value to give the highest result between them and execute a command based on that?

I'm looking for something like:

```
If x > y > z > q Then 'command
```

Comment: Put them in an array and call `Max` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your value in a list, you can get the max value by calling Max()

```
    Dim a, b, c, d As Double

    a = 10
    b = 3
    c = 33
    d = 15

    Dim listOfDouble As New List(Of Double)({a, b, c, d})
    Dim maxValue As Double = listOfDouble.Max()
```

As @jmcilhinney noted, we could just use an array.

```
    Dim arrayOfDouble As Double() = {a, b, c, d}
    Dim maxValue As Double = arrayOfDouble.Max()
```

Comment: Not much point creating a `List` from an array when you can call `Max` on the array.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants. It looks like he wants to make sure that `a > b` and `b > c` and so on.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the sample code is telling a different story than the text.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed The op specifically says "to give the highest result between them"

Comment: @DavidWilson, perhaps you're right but as the_lotus has said, the sample code says something else. So, I guess only the OP can confirm what he/she actually meant :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yep - and it seems very quiet there :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if `x > y` and `y > z` and `z > q`. If that's the case, you can use something like:

```
If x > y AndAlso y > z AndAlso z > q Then

End If
```

However, this can get longer when you have more numbers and I assume you're looking for something more generic. Something like this would be what you're looking for:

```
Dim x, y, z, q As Double
x = 5
y = 7
z = 2
q = 14

Dim asArray As Double() = {x, y, z, q}
Dim sorted = asArray.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i)
If asArray.SequenceEqual(sorted) Then
    ' Do your thing.
End If
```

Comment: OK thank you all and sorry for the confusion, yes it's as you said to get the highest value and the ones blow it. But further more i want to know the values of x,y,z,q knowing that they change every time so i need to know whose highest and descending.

Comment: @AceSiddig I'm not sure I understand. Did you try the code in my answer? What do you expect it to do but it doesn't? If you think you need to add more info, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51176151/edit) to include that info.